# JS YouTube iframe API: Uncaught TypeError: player.loadVideoByUrl is not a function

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, browser, youtube

```js
let youtubeAPITag = document.createElement("script");

youtubeAPITag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(youtubeAPITag, firstScriptTag);

let ready = false;
let player;

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
    player = new YT.Player("test", {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        videoId: "M7lc1UVf-VE"
    });
    player.loadVideoByUrl("https://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
    console.log(player);
};
```

[image: Error Showing]

`loadVideoById` doesn't also work. By using `console.log(player)`, it is sure that the player is loaded. Is there any way to solve this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLzygqbc/)

Comment: I found the solution for this. I replaced `<iframe id="test"></iframe>` into `<div id="test"></div>` so that the API could replace the element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.